# shift from self-hosted Parse-Server to Amazon SNS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, push-notification, amazon-sns

Hi i want to shift my self hosted Parse server to Amazon SNS and all the guides i have found online only show options to export data from parse.com dashboard and not self hosted parse / parse-dashboard, for example the following link:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/migrating-from-parse-push-to-amazon-sns/

My self hosted parse setup is using mongodb on a digitalocean droplet. Is there anyway i can export this mongodb to Amazon SNS without losing any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of being on Parse-Server is that you're now in charge of managing your database, which it seems you've delegated to digital ocean. Do they host through mLab? I haven't used them, but I know that's what Heroku does.

If you have access to your database directly, look into this documentation: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/04/aws-database-migration-service-adds-support-for-mongodb-and-amazon-dynamodb/

Otherwise, you may need to contact digital ocean and have them help migrate your data. I'd be shocked if they don't hand you the keys to their upcharged DB though.

Comment: Thanks, youve been great help. i figured out how to export json file from mongodb and convert it into appropriate format to import it in amazon sns. But now im facing another issue, please see if you can help or point me towards someone who can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606908/amazon-sns-import-parse-server-data-as-json