# AMAZON SNS import Parse Server Data as JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am shifting my self-hosted parse to Amazon SNS and have followed all instructions on this link properly:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/migrating-from-parse-push-to-amazon-sns/

Now on step 4: Import Parse Push data when i run the java code

```
java -jar SNSImportTool.jar -s -f   <PATH_TO_EXPORTED_PARSE_INSTALLATION_.JSON_FILE>
--apnsName <APNS_PLATFORM_APP_NAME_STEP_3.2.9>
--gcmName <GCM_PLATFORM_APP_NAME_STEP_3.2.9>
--topicName <SNS_TOPIC_NAME_STEP_3.2.10>
--awsaccess <AWS_KEY_ID_STEP_3.3>
--awssecret <SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_STEP_3.3>
```

i get the following output:

```
===========================================
Import from Parse to Amazon SNS
===========================================

Verify platform application: app/GCM/appname_MOBILEHUB_111111
Verify platform application: app/APNS/appname_MOBILEHUB_111111

Created 1 channel topics:SNS

Processing token APA91bEApdQ5PFqX77X53LZZevzw9ghwxuhvBwPu5E4Z1og1TTYTLFHv3oF5-AMszqZDfSBWCH4dn_zYK4Emx21j-30k6u0SGQ4KHbAWuuYbPCzSRm-9hvU
Could not create endpoint: Invalid parameter: PlatformApplicationArn Reason: Wrong number of slashes in relative portion of the ARN. (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: 12b597de-1a46-5168-b1af-c661430db91f)

Processing token d806a7e6701df9250d8162e47b15ff78b857b285de38113d1b7f504ea92d46b5
Could not create endpoint: PlatformApplication does not exist (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NotFound; Request ID: 419d4827-9238-5d46-a584-1998cb74e16e)
```

to clarify, for items in json that have deviceType as android i get the following error:

```
Invalid parameter: PlatformApplicationArn Reason: Wrong number of slashes in relative portion of the ARN
```

and deviceType as ios i get the following error:

```
Could not create endpoint: PlatformApplication does not exist
```

my json file looks like this:

```
{"results":[{ "channels" : ["SNS"], "_id" : "000f0KsszOH1", "_updated_at" : "2017-06-11T00:03:10.712+0000" ,  "UniqueId" : "79bb118ec2b71c3f", "appIdentifier" : "com.leApp", "parseVersion" : "1.8.0", "timeZone" : "Asia/Riyadh", "installationId" : "f05f3d8a-f045-35fe-a268-855eda3b2c78", "appVersion" : "2.2.8", "deviceType" : "ios", "_created_at" : "2015-12-15T12:49:23.954+0000", "pushType" : "gcm","deviceToken" : "APA99bEApdQ5PFqX77X53LYYevzw4ghwxuhvBwPu4C3Z1og1TTYTLFHv3oF5-AMszqZDfSBWCH4dn_zYK4Emx21j-30k6u0SGQ4KHbAWuuYbPCzSRm-9hvU", "localeIdentifier" : "en-GB" }]}
```

please advise how to fix these errors.

Comment: What did you pass for `--topicName` in step 4?

Comment: i created a topic name by visiting https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v2/home?region=us-east-1#/topics/ and it created an ARN like the following
`arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:the_topic` and so i added only the `the_topic` bit like this: `--topicName the_topic`